# How to set cookie from a domain into a subdomain

Tags: cookies, https, cross-domain, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

This is a protocol question - not related to a specific programming language.

Let's say we currently have:

- a website using the domain: `example.com`
- a frontend app at: `example.com/example-front`
- an API at: `example.com/api/example-data`
- all addresses using HTTPS.
- The front-end app calls the API to log in and gets a `set-cookie: data=SOME_DATA; Secure; httpOnly; Path=/; Domain=example.com` and it works as expected.

1. We want to transfer the frontend app from `example.com/example-front` to `front.example.com`.
2. The API will stay at the same address.

#### What should be done (frontend / backend / subdomain gateway) in order to make this work?

(already tried to set `domain=.example.com` and `sameSite=None`).

Answer (score 1):

After checked everything needed to do and verified it in production too, the steps to resolve this issue are:

#### From the frontend perspective:

- if you’re using axios / XHR - add withCredentials: true
- if you’re using fetch - add credentials: true

#### From the backend perspective (the API):

1. Add header: “access-control-allow-origin: [specify the specific subdomain, including protocol. E.g: https://sub.example.com]”
2. Add “access-control-allow-credentials: true”
3. At the “set-cookie” header, you should mention: “httpOnly; secure; domain=example.com; sameSite=None;”